# How do I convert any Timestamp string to a single Format in Java

Tags: java, date, datetime, time, timestamp

I want to convert the timestamps which are in different formats to one format
I want to convert following timestamps to single format

`Time Stamp 1 : 2022-08-17T18:28:07.288496+05:30`

`Time Stamp 2 : 2022-10-27T13:17:47.987736542Z`

to

`yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss` format

I have tried using `DateFormatter` of Java but it gives ParseException. Also used `SimpleDateFormatter` but was getting same exceptions.
Please suggest package or methods for the same.

Edit : Code I used for conversion

```java
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(timestamp, formatter);
System.out.println(localDateTime);
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and include the code that threw the `DateTimeParseException`? Preferably the one where you used a `DateTimeFormatter`…

Comment: Short answer - it’s hard and messy. Essentially, you need to create a list for formats and the loop over this list trying to parse the String till you either get a result or run out of formats

Comment: Is there no way to do these without maintaining a list for the same

Comment: Sure, @MadProgrammer when there are more possible formats than just the two from the example `String`s, your statement will be totally right. For those two examples, it's easy with `OffsetDateTime`.

Comment: Short answer, it’s straightforward and easy since both of your formats are really the same, just variants of [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), and the one-arg `OffsetDateTime.parse()` handles both without even requiring us to specify a formatter. Also @MadProgrammer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `java.time` here is a good idea compared to `java.util.Date`, `Calendar` and so on, but you have to use specific classes that match the information inside a `String` that represents a datetime or timestamp.

In your case, the `String` contains the following information:

- year
- month of year
- day of month
- hour of day
- minute of hour
- second of minute
- fractions of second
- offset from UTC

In particular, it's the last one (offset from UTC) which makes your attempt fail because you (1) don't consider it in the pattern of the `DateTimeFormatter` and (2) you use a class that cannot store it (`LocalDateTime` is not able / designed to hold information about a zone or an offset.

Having `String`s with an offset can be stored in / parsed to `OffsetDateTime`s, if they are ISO formatted (as your examples are), you don't even need to apply a custom `DateTimeFormatter`. You can simply call `OffsetDateTime.parse(String)`.

You can then define a desired format for an output by creating a custom `DateTimeFormatter` and apply it in `OffsetDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter)`.

Here's an example:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // example Strings (your ones)
    String timestampOne = "2022-08-17T18:28:07.288496+05:30";
    String timestampTwo = "2022-10-27T13:17:47.987736542Z";
    // directly parse them to get instances of OffsetDateTime
    OffsetDateTime odtOne = OffsetDateTime.parse(timestampOne);
    OffsetDateTime odtTwo = OffsetDateTime.parse(timestampTwo);
    // prepare a formatter for your desired output
    DateTimeFormatter dtfOut = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    // and print the values of the OffsetDateTimes formatted by that DateTimeFormatter
    System.out.println(odtOne.format(dtfOut));
    System.out.println(odtTwo.format(dtfOut));
}
```

Output:

```
2022-08-17T18:28:07
2022-10-27T13:17:47
```